# Se puede hacer un boton de 'ME GUSTA' de corazón, usando dos imagenes?

Tags: javascript, html, css

necestio cambiar de una imagen que es un boton a otra seria algo asi:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y que se vuelva asi:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

digamos quiero que de la primera imagen se remplaze por la segunda imagen, dandole click a el boton, es posible ?
he intentando de todo este es mi codigo:

mi HTML:

```html
       <button class="cora" type="button" >
         <img class="megusta" src="imagenes/me gusta.svg" alt="Me gusta" />
         <!-- <img class="megustaN" src="imagenes/mgnegro.svg" alt="Me gusta" /> -->
       </button>
```

mi CSS:

```css
         
.megusta {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.megusta:hover {
  opacity: 0.4;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.megusta:active {
  transform: scale(0.9);
}

.megustaN {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0; 
  transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.cora {
  border: 0;
  background: none;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-top: 13px;
}
```

y aqui mi JS:

```js
// 1.seleccion
const cambiarboton = document.querySelector("megusta")
console.log("cambiarboton", cambiarboton);

cambiarboton.addEventListener("click", function(){

 megusta.style.display = imagen1.style.display === "none" ? "block" : "none";
    megustan.style.display = imagen2.style.display === "none" ? "block" : "none";

});
```

intentado de todo pero siempre me aprecen los dos corazones,se puede cambiar una imagen por otra haciendo click con js ??

Comment: Esta pregunta te la respondimos ayer, cual es el problema??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te dejo varios puntos y una idea de solución:

1. El contenedor de tus corazones (el `<button>`) tiene un posicionamiento static, lo que hace que se muestre un corazón al lado del otro.
2. Tu constante cambiarboton no debería de estar apuntando a "megusta" sino a "megustaN"
3. Puedes resolver este problema sin usar javascript y solo con estilos.

Idea de solución:

```css
.megusta {
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 200px;
}

.megusta:hover {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 0.3s;
  transform: scale(0.9);
}

.megusta:hover +  .megustaN{
  opacity: 1; 
}

.megustaN {
  pointer-events: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0; 
  transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out;
  width: 200px;
}

.cora {
  border: 0;
  background: none;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-top: 13px;
}
```

```html
<button class="cora" type="button" >
   <img class="megusta" src="https://svgsilh.com/svg_v2/24037.svg" alt="Me gusta" />
   <img class="megustaN" src="https://svgsilh.com/svg/1093169.svg" alt="Me gusta" />
 </button>
```

Te dejo un link en donde puedes ver este ejemplo funcionando:
https://codepen.io/giless/pen/zYyjgod

Comment: Buenas, gioless, bienvenido al sitio. Creo que ese no es el efecto deseado. Esta pregunta es un duplicado del mismo usuario que la ha formulado varias veces, puedes ver la respuesta con el efecto deseado [aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/604433/5896)

Comment: Tienes razón @RubioRic, gracias por la aclaración

Comment: Nada. Otra cosa, si te fijas, se puede incrustar en la propia respuesta el código javascript de forma que se visualicen sus efectos, sin necesidad de recurrir a páginas externas. Para la siguiente :-)

Comment: Joya! Muchas gracias